# Page bars not hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

```
</body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>  
        </div>
    </div>

/css
.container{
    padding: 10px 10%;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #ff004f;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -6px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
```

I am making a hover effect for the pages for my portfolio website. Everything else is working but the hovering does not. I added ul and used li as I usually do but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `nav ul li a::after` has `width:100%` change it to `width: 0%;`

**Note:** I have changed the color of text to make it visible here, add your color to your code.

## Demo

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px 10%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ff004f;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -6px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
</body>
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i have tweaked and added a llittle more

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background: #080808;
    color: #fff;
}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(Untitled-2.png) ;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.container{
    padding: 10px 10%;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.logo{
    width: 140px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #ff0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: -6px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #ff004f;
}
.header-text{
    margin-top: 5%;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.header-text h1{
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.header-text h1 span{
    color: #ff004f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal Portfolio Website - Rishith Dandu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>  
            <div class="header-text">
                <p>UI/UX Designer/Full Stack Devoloper</p>
                <h1>Hi,I'm <span>Rishith</span><br>Dandu From India</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="about-col-1"></div>
            <div class="about-col-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```